# Using existing database for Mobile App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

Right now, my ASP.NET MVC site is hosted on Azure using an App Service.
However it is critical that I can send push notifications to my users, thus I figured I'd develop a mobile app (Android & iPhone).

I have created a test project and see that the example model looks the following:

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

It inherits from EntityData which has properties such as Id and Deleted.

The database models of my current project do not inheirit from EntityData.

Is it possible to still use my current model (and current dbcontext) (from my web app) in a mobile app even though those models don't inherit from EntityData?

Comment: since there are properties (possibly) not in your database, you'll have to inject a different configuration to ignore those properties.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro

"Inject a different configuration" - what are you referring to here?

Comment: Are you talking about a server side database, or a database hosted on the client's mobile device?

Comment: you could configure your context differently depending on some flag, or simply use other DbSets depending on this and drop the columns of the enhanced entities.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice, then Xamarin is a great choice for the client-side - you can use almost identical code for the models on the client and server - in fact, a lot of people create an "EntityData" abstract base class with the right fields in it (Id, UpdatedAt and Version) to support incremental sync and optimistic concurrency.  In the case of an Android or iOS native app, you will want to adjust your model on the client side in the same way.

For an example on the Xamarin side, see this project: https://github.com/adrianhall/30-days-of-zumo-v2/tree/master/file-upload - this contains both a backend and a Xamarin client for Android and iOS.